# Higher Order Component can't access Wrapped Component's default props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, react-router

I have an HOC like so:

```
export default function HOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
      i: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    };

    render() {
console.log(this.props);
      return <WrappedComponent
        {...this.props}/>;
    }
  };
}
```

And my wrapped component is like so:

```
WrappedComponent extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
      i: 0
    };

    render() {
      return <div/>;
    }
  };

export default HOC(WrappedComponent);
```

In my console.log in the HOC, i is not defined. The props passed into WrappedComponent by its parent are, however, defined in the HOC. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to make something like: `class HOC extends WrappedComponent` ?

Comment: @YUzhva I'm pretty sure that's against React convention

Comment: which version of react are you using ?

Comment: notice, that you missed `class` before `WrappedComponent`. It should be like: `class WrappedComponent extends Component {}`

Answer (score 1):

That is example based on official React [Higher-order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) documentation:

```js
class HOC extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<p>{this.props.defaultPropAsExtreFeature}</p>);
  }
};

function createHOCWithExtraFeatures(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
      defaultPropAsExtreFeature: "You will be able to see me at HOC"
    };
    
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

const ExtendedHoc = createHOCWithExtraFeatures(HOC);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExtendedHoc />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Option #2

You could create `React.Component` and than just extend it like:

```js
class HOC extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    HOCDefaultValue: 'You will be able to see me as WrappedComponent property',
  };

  render() {
    return (<p>1</p>);
  }
};

// NOTE: WrappedComponent doesn't have any properties
// it inherit them from HOC
class WrappedComponent extends HOC {
  render() {
    return (<p>{this.props.HOCDefaultValue}</p>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <WrappedComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The benefit of the 1st method is that everytime you are using `createHOCWithExtraFeatures` you are creating a new component and you could assign it to some `const`.